# Getting different amount of cell values from each row in a table from selenium on each loop

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I am trying to create a code that can get the values from a table using selenium. I am successfully getting these values from each row, but the number of rows are different each time I run the code.

## Here is the code I currently have:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time
options = Options()
options.headless = True
with open('table_data.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write('')
    f.close

initialize the webdriver
# go to the webpage containing the table
def find_profitable_rows(file_path):
    profitable_rows = []
    with open(file_path, 'r') as file:
        for i, line in enumerate(file):
            # skip the header row
            if i == 0:
                continue
            row_data = line.strip().split('|')
            if len(row_data) >= 4:
                try:
                    ask_price = float(row_data[2])
                    bid_price = float(row_data[3])
                    diff = bid_price - ask_price
                    if diff > 1000:
                        profitable_rows.append(row_data)
                except ValueError:
                    # skip rows with invalid prices
                    continue
    return profitable_rows
     
     
def GetValues(Url):
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
    driver.get(Url)

    row_data = []
    # find the table
    table = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.TAG_NAME, "table")))

    # open the file in append mode
    with open('table_data.txt', 'a') as file:

        # find all the rows in the table
        rows = table.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "tr")

        # loop through each row
        for row in rows:
            # find all the cells in the row
            cells = row.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "td")

            # create a list to store the cell values for this row
            row_data = []
            cells = cells[2:-7]
            # loop through each cell in the row
            for cell in cells:
                time.sleep(.25)
                text = cell.text.strip()
                if text:
                    row_data.append(text)
            if row_data:
                with open("table_data.txt", "a") as file:
                    file.write("\n".join(row_data) + "\n\n")

            # print the row data
            print(row_data)

        # close the webdriver
    driver.quit()


urls = ["link1","link2","link3"]
for Url in urls : 
    GetValues(Url)
x= find_profitable_rows("table_data.txt")
print(x)
```

I am tried implementing time delays, hoping that would make it grab the same amount of cells each time, but that has not worked.

Comment: your question is incomplete unless you provide the input `urls` and content of the `txt` file. So, Please help us to help you.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example